# Consulta SQL con PHP

Tags: sql

Estoy editando un sistema de reservas con `PHP` y quiero hacer unas consultas.
Tengo 3 Tablas

```
w_clases

w_clientes

w_reservas
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen estoy intentando hacer una consulta con un formulario que ponga fecha inicio y fecha fin y me lo muestre, llevo esto para la consulta:

```
SELECT cl.nombre,c.nombre From w_reservas R 
INNER JOIN wp_clases cl on R.id_clase =cl.id 
INNER JOIN w_clientes c on cl.id = r.id_usuario 
WHERE r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
```

Pero no consigo que funcione, en resumen en la consulta quiero que aparezca:

```
Nombre clase | Fecha Clase | Hora clase | Nombre Usuario
-------------|-------------|------------|---------------
```

Comment: ¿En tu segundo `Inner join` es correcto que uses `cl.id` en vez de `c.id`?

Comment: ¿Puedes decir en la pregunta **cómo** están relacionadas tus tablas? Haciendo ese pequeño ejercicio quizá encuentres la respuesta por ti mismo. Ya que dices que no funciona... **¿qué no funciona?**, ¿la consulta muestra algo? ¿no muestra nada? Por último, si quieres 4 columnas en tu resultado debes tener esas 4 columnas en el `SELECT...`, ahora mismo sólo estás seleccionando 2 columnas,  ¿de dónde sacarás las otras 2 si no las incluyes en el `SELECT...`?

Comment: Creo que todo esta perfecto, salvo 2 detalles que tu mismo debes verificar, primero: realmente existen reservas `BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'` (la que muestras en la imagen esta fuera de ese periodo), y segundo, el `w_reservas.id_usuario` es clave foranea de `w_clientes.id` o de `w_clientes.id_usuario`. Espero confirmación de esas verificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT cl.nombre,c.nombre From w_reservas r 
INNER JOIN wp_clases cl on r.id_clase =cl.id 
INNER JOIN w_clientes c on c.id = r.id_usuario 
WHERE r.fecha_reserva BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es:

```
select
    nombre_clase = cl.nombre,
    fecha_clase = r.fecha_reserva,
    hora_clase = cl.hora,
    nombre_usuario = c.nombre,
    apellidos_usuario = c.apellidos
from
    w_reservas r
    inner join w_clases cl on
        cl.id = r.id_clase
    inner join w_clientes c on
        c.id = r.id_usuario
where
    r.fecha_reserva between '2014-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
order by
    r.fecha_reserva, r.id_clase, c.nombre, c.apellidos
```